# How to make JQuery TreeView nodes into links?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-plugins

I've just created a navigation tree for a help page using ASP.NET MVC and JQuery TreeView.

I can't figure out how to add links to the child nodes. What I want to do is add a property to my model (string linkText) so I can set it in each child node and turn them into links.

Inserting an `a` tag between `li` tags needs to be done in the jquery.treeview.js file, right?

I'd appreciate any help! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

use `.wrapInner()` **http://api.jquery.com/wrapInner/**

**Demo** : **http://jsfiddle.net/QSDxJ/**

Comment: I ended up hard coding links in (acceptable in this particular application). Thanks for the response though!